# How do I transform a JSON fields into a Seq in Scala Play framework 2?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.5

I have some JSON coming from an external API which I have no control over. Part of the JSON is formatted like this:

```
{
  "room_0": {
    "area_sq_ft": 151.2
  },
  "room_1": {
    "area_sq_ft": 200.0
  }
}
```

Instead of using an array like they should have, they've used room_n for a key to n number of elements. Instead of creating a case class with room_0, room_1, room_2, etc., I want to convert this to a Seq[Room] where this is my Room case class:

```
case class Room(area: Double)
```

I am using Reads from `play.api.libs.json` for converting other parts of the JSON to case classes and would prefer to use Reads for this conversion. How could I accomplish that?

Here's what I've tried.

```
val sqFtReads = (__ \ "size_sq_ft").read[Double]
val roomReads = (__ \ "size_sq_ft").read[Seq[Room]](sqFtReads).map(Room) 
cmd19.sc:1: overloaded method value read with alternatives:
  (t: Seq[$sess.cmd17.Room])play.api.libs.json.Reads[Seq[$sess.cmd17.Room]] <and>
  (implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Seq[$sess.cmd17.Room]])play.api.libs.json.Reads[Seq[$sess.cmd17.Room]]
 cannot be applied to (play.api.libs.json.Reads[Double])
val roomReads = (__ \ "size_sq_ft").read[Seq[Room]](sqFtReads).map(Room)
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson)? What have you tried?

Comment: @cchantep yes, I've been over the docs a few times, but I haven't seen anything that helps me with this use case.

Comment: First the JSON example is not an array (corresponding to a Scala collection such as `Seq`) of room, but a dictionnary with keys `room_0` and `room_1`. Then you'd better have a look at Play JSON macros to define a `Reads[Room]`.

Comment: Correct, it's not an array. It's a bad implementation of an array and I need to fix it before I pass it on. That's the main point of my question. I should have made that more clear. I was hoping there was some kind of wildcard search for node names, then I could split on the _ to get "room" and 0 and use that to add the value to a list, or something like that.

Comment: Even having keys named `0`/`1` wouldn't not turn this JSON object into a JSON array (wrong representation). You could use JSON transformers to fix this before parsing, but would this be simpler/more efficient than working with an appropriate JSON source?

Comment: I wish I could change the source, but unfortunately, it's out of my control. Are you referring to the JSON transformers documented [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135428/discussion-between-matt-olsen-and-cchantep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tricky little challenge but completely achievable with `Reads`.

First, `Reads[Room]` - i.e. the converter for a single `Room` instance:

```
val roomReads = new Reads[Room] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Room] = {
    (json \ "area_sq_ft").validate[Double].map(Room(_))
  }
}
```

Pretty straightforward; we peek into the JSON and try to find a top-level field called `area_sq_ft` which validates as a `Double`. If it's all good, we return the populated `Room` instance as needed.

Next up, the converter for your upstream object that in good [Postel's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) fashion, you are cleaning up for your own consumers.

```
val strangeObjectReads = new Reads[Seq[Room]] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Seq[Room]] = {

    json.validate[JsObject].map { jso =>

      val roomsSortedNumerically = jso.fields.sortBy { case (name, contents) =>
        val numericPartOfRoomName = name.dropWhile(!_.isDigit)
        numericPartOfRoomName.toInt
      }

      roomsSortedNumerically.map { case (name, contents) =>
        contents.as[Room](roomReads)
      }

    }
  }
}
```

The key thing here is the `json.validate[JsObject]` around the whole lot. By `map`ping over this we get the `JsResult` that we need to wrap the whole thing, plus, we can get access to the `fields` inside the JSON object, which is defined as a `Seq[(String, JsValue)]`.

To ensure we put the fields in the correct order in the output sequence, we do a little bit of string manipulation, getting the numeric part of the `room_1` string, and using that as the `sortBy` criteria. I'm being a bit naive here and assuming your upstream server won't do anything nasty like skip room numbers!

Once you've got the rooms sorted numerically, we can just `map` over them, converting each one with our `roomReads` converter.

You've probably noticed that my custom `Reads` implementations are most definitely **not** one-liners. This comes from bitter experience dealing with oddball upstream JSON formats. Being a bit verbose, using a few more variables and breaking things up a bit pays off big time when that upstream server changes its JSON format suddenly!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @millhouse!